# How to debug the PHP 5 runtime on Windows with Visual Studio?

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio, debugging

Back in the PHP 4 days, you could load up the PHP runtime source code in Visual Studio via dsw files. Now with PHP 5 they introduced a new build system that is command line based. This means you can't easily load up PHP into Visual Studio and start a debugging session with the GUI setting breakpoints, using watches, etc.

How would you recommend I set up a debugging environment for PHP 5 on Windows? Right now it seems like quite the monumental task, but I'm hoping there is an easier way.

This is the step-by-step build instructions for Windows on the PHP wiki: http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Answer (score 1):

PHP's debugger [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) can be used with Visual Studio.

Unfortuantely, althoug XDebug itself is free, integrating it with Visual Studio requires a [commercial plug-in](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php). (it's only $99 though, so that may not be too steep).

See also here for a list of all the IDEs (the XDebug author knows about) that have direct support for XDebug or plug-ins: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote.

I note that there's also a [stand-alone Windows client for XDebug](http://code.google.com/p/xdebugclient/), which is free, so if you can't stretch to the commercial VS plugin, that might be good enough for you; it still allows you to step through code; just not in your main IDE.

Comment: This is a couple of years old. It looks like VS.Php uses PHP Version 5.3.18 or newer at the moment (screenshot on their website), but our version of PHP is older. I don't mind having the company fork over $99 for me, but I do not want to submit this request if I can't set PHP to the version that our server is running.

Comment: @jp2code - You didn't state which PHP version your server is using, other than being older than 5.3.18. But if that means it's running 5.2 or earlier, you should be urgently considering an upgrade anyway. 5.2 has been unsupported for several years now and has known security issues that should not be anywhere near a production server. Older versions of 5.3 likewise. It's important to keep up to date with security patches.

Comment: It looks like management has a ticket in the works to upgrade our PHP, but it requires testing on a lot of our stuff before it can happen. We are not that old, but still at 5.3.10.

Comment: If you're planning to upgrade to 5.4 or 5.5, then yes, you probably do need to do a systems test. But there shouldn't be an issue updating to the latest 5.3 release; there aren't any breaking changes between 5.3.10 and 5.3.28; the difference between them is almost entirely security fixes. You shouldn't need to do a full system test just to get a security patch release.